# Topological sort orderings on a disconnected DAG

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

If the numbers 0,1,2 are nodes in a directed acyclic graph and we have only 1 edge: `1 -> 2`. Then all valid orderings are:

```
 1,2,0
 0,1,2
 1,0,2
```

Am I correct? I'm only not sure about the last ordering:  `1,0,2` Is it valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), the only condition for topological ordering is that for every directed edge `u->v` u should come before v. It is not said that it should come just before v.

Consider the vertices to represent tasks to be performed, say you getting ready.
Say 0 is putting on a tie, 1 is wearing a pair of socks and 2 is wearing shoes. Thus 1 comes before 2(1->2). As you can see, the last ordering you have written, can be considered to be a topological order(Wear socks, then tie and then your shoes)